# General file pathing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a command to get a general file path in MATLAB. I'm looking to be able to run my code across multiple computers.

Example

```
fullfile('','C:','users','XXXXXX','Desktop','Matlab Data')
```

Is it possible to get this `fullfile` location off of where the MATLAB code is stored so that it can be used later in the code for file execution, regardless of what computer it's executing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within a function called `foo`:

```
function x = foo( )
        x=fullfile(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')),'lorem','ipsum');
        % fun stuff
end
```

This should work regardless of your current working directory.

Comment: I'm finally getting around to this, am I understanding this right that the mfilename('fullpath') will pull the current working directory and then the lorem ipsum would be sub folders past this?

Comment: @aaron That's almost correct, but rather than the current working directory, we are determining here the folder where the file invoking `mfilename()` is stored, even if it is not the CWD. This difference can be meaningful when you manipulate the search path with e.g. `addpath()`, store your file in special locations such as a "`private`" subfolder, etc. Other than that, your explanation is correct: `lorem` and `ipsum` are nested nodes (not necessarily regular folders) at the deeper end of the assembled path.